# clarification about offset in assemblywin32

Tags: assembly

I'm a newbie and self-learner at Assembly and have seen the use of OFFSET in different contexts but still am not clear, so please, explain.

Is offset in this example a pointer to MenuName?

```
invoke LoadMenu, hInst, OFFSET MenuName
```

Or is offset passing the address of MenuName to a procedure?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which assembler. This looks like Masm (or Tasm), so yes it means the address of `MenuName`. In AT&T syntax, you'd use `$MenuName` to indicate the address. Just `MenuName` would indicate contents of the variable. In Nasm syntax, `[MenuName]` would indicate contents, and just `MenuName` would be the address. There's a reason why we ask ya to say which assembler! :)

Comment: It is Masm. Very clear your answer.Thank you very much, Frank. Very clear your answer.